# How to translate the expression "ready, steady, go"?

Tags: translation

In running, to start the competition, someone shouts "Ready, steady, go!". Is there a common Esperanto translation for this? Are there any real usage examples?

Comment: Interesting.  Where I'm from it's "ready, set, go".

Answer (score 6):

Wiktionary and Tatoeba have the phrase "Atentu, pretu, ek!", which seems very good to me.

Answer (score 5):

**"Surlokiĝu, pretu, ek!"**

Gives some more time to the athletes and is closer to the German expression *"Auf die Plätze, fertig, los"*

Comment: and also closer to the English expression "on your mark, get set, go".

Answer (score 4):

**"Komencu, pretu, ek!"**

It is charming because of the number of syllables (3, 2, 1) corresponding to the countdown.

I know of no usage examples, I have never seen a competition like this with Esperanto as a language.

Comment: Next IJK maybe. 

Comment: This would be a bit confusing since "komencu" already means "start", but the runner should *not* start when they hear "komencu", but only be at their starting *position*.

Answer (score 1):

Evidente, ĉiuj simple proponas ekzaktajn tradukojn de respektivaj frazoj el siaj naciaj lingvoj, ĉar ne ekzistas la kutima esprimo esperante. :) Do mi faros la samon.

En la rusa lingvo tiuj komandoj estas "На старт, внимание, марш!". Do la traduko estas:
"Startlinie, atentu, ek!".
Alia varianto: 
"Startpozicie, atentu, ek!".